# App doesn't get fully launched with Instruments (Allocations) on the device

Tags: iphone, xcode, instruments, ios4

Instruments launches my app on the device and listens to the allocations. (In "Allocations" mode) It launches extremely slow. Then the app quits after about 35 seconds. On the simulator Instruments runs fine.
Is there a solution to this? Is iOS killing my app? How am I supposed to debug this if Instruments increases launch time that much?

Thanks in advance

I'm on a iPhone 3G (iOS 4) with XCode 3.2.3

Answer (score 0):

Any message from Instruments.app? I have had a similiar problem until I build for the device in debug mode and used a development provisioning profile for it. A distribution profile even compiling fine in debug mode hasn't done the job.